# Neo4j: how to avoid node to be created again if it is already in the database?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a question about Cypher requests and the update of a database.
I have a python script that does web scraping and generate a csv at the end. I use this csv to import data in a neo4j database.

The scraping is done 5 times a day. So every time a new scraping is done the csv is updated, new data is added to the the previous csv and so on.
I import the data after each scraping.
Actually when I import the data after each scraping to update the DB, I have all the nodes created again even if it is already in the DB.

For example the first csv gives 5 rows and I insert this in Neo4j.
Next the new scraping gives 2 rows so the csv has now 7 rows. And if I insert the data I will have the first five rows twice in the DB.
I would like to have everything unique and not added if it is already in the database.

For example when I try to create node ARTICLE I do this:

```
CREATE (a:ARTICLE {id:$id, title:$title, img_url:$img_url, link:$link, sentence:$sentence, published:$published})
```

I think MERGE instead of CREATE should solve the solution, but it doesn't and I can't figure it out why.

How can I do this ?

Comment: If you create an index with a constraint on the id field, then the creation routine will flag an error if you try to create the same node twice. You're better off cleaning the data before-hand (I've found this to be necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) clause will **create** its entire pattern if *any* part of it does not already exist. So, for a `MERGE` clause to work reasonably, the pattern used with it must only specify the *minimum* data necessary to uniquely identify a node (or a relationship).

For instance, assuming `ARTICLE` nodes are supposed to have unique `id` properties, then you should replace your `CREATE` clause:

```
CREATE (a:ARTICLE {id:$id, title:$title, img_url:$img_url, link:$link, sentence:$sentence, published:$published})
```

with something like this:

```
MERGE (a:ARTICLE {id:$id})
SET a += {title:$title, img_url:$img_url, link:$link, sentence:$sentence, published:$published}
```

In the above example, the `SET` clause will always overwrite the non-`id` properties. If you want to set those properties only when the node is created, you can use [ON CREATE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/#merge-merge-with-on-create) before the `SET` clause.

Comment: Thank you, I saw that I have NaN values in some columns of the article dataframe. I replaced them by 'no content' and MERGE seems to work now. I think it was it but I don't understand why it is a problem?

Comment: I also do NER on articles and when I do NER on new scraping same NER nodes are created. I don't understand why

Comment: You have not shown enough information or code (e.g., how are you generating the parameters to pass to the Cypher code, and what your actual CYpher code now looks like, etc.). Also, what does "NER" mean? And what are the actual error messages you are getting? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MERGE` instead of `CREATE`. You can use it for both nodes and relationships.

```
MERGE (charlie { name: 'Charlie Sheen', age: 10 })
```

Create a single node with properties where not all properties match any existing node.

```
MATCH (a:Person {name: "Martin"}),
      (b:Person {name: "Marie"})
MERGE (a)-[r:LOVES]->(b)
```

Finds or creates a relationship between the nodes.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but it doesn't work. Nodes are created again even if it exists in the database

Comment: I think MERGE should solve the solution, but I can't figure it out why it doesn't